# 'Batt_Temperature_Table' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: android, c, linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to compile an android kernel and am getting this error:

```
mediatek/platform/mt6589/kernel/drivers/power/mt6320_battery.c: In function' BattThermistorConverTemp':
mediatek/platform/mt6589/kernel/drivers/power/mt6320_battery.c:1361:14: error: 'Batt_Temperature_Table' undeclared (first use in this function)
     if(Res>= Batt_Temperature_Table[0].TemperatureR)
              ^
mediatek/platform/mt6589/kernel/drivers/power/mt6320_battery.c:1361:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  CC [M]  mediatek/platform/mt6589/kernel/drivers/masp/asf/core/alg_aes_so.o
  CC [M]  mediatek/platform/mt6589/kernel/drivers/dual_ccci/asf/core/sec_ops.o
make[2]: ** *[mediatek/platform/mt6589/kernel/drivers/power/mt6320_battery.o] Error 1
make[1]: ** *[mediatek/platform/mt6589/kernel/drivers/power] Error 2
make[1]: ** *Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Here is the code:
mt6320_battery.c: http://pastebin.com/thGQLNS9

mt6320_battery.h: http://pastebin.com/tfekgst6

I don't see anything wrong with the code. Please Help!

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at lines where Batt_Temperature_Table is defined: it located inside "ifdef" condition like #if defined(BAT_NTC_10_SEN_1) . You provided only *.c file, while as such definitions surely located in *.h files (or in Kconfig).

Comment: here is the *.h file: http://pastebin.com/tfekgst6

Comment: I guess you need another header, cust_battery.h - I googled it, and there is definitions that could be configured: check #define BAT_NTC_10, BAT_NTC_47 , e.t.c